# Why this error: "require is not defined" in Gulp?

Tags: sass, gulp, eslint

I am trying to use Gulp in my project. i have done following things

1. `$ sudo npm install gulp -g .` - to install Gulp globally
2. `$ npm init` - from my project path
3. `npm install gulp --save-dev`

Here is my `gulpfile.js`:

[image]
I am not sure why I am getting this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ESLint: How to set .eslintrc to recognize 'require'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901417/eslint-how-to-set-eslintrc-to-recognize-require)

Comment: no help from above question

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a linter error.  What's your **.eslintrc** file look like?

Try adding `env.node` **.eslintrc**

```
{
  "env" : {
    "node" : true
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont have such file.. I have package.json is that your are saying?

Comment: you mean in node modules? and do i need to run eslint --init command in project level or globally.. i tried but saying command not found

Comment: I am not sure from where i will get eslintrc file